# can we start cursor from center of the editText without using gravity

Tags: android, xml

I had a layout in which i am using EditText i want to start the cursor from center of hint but i can't use gravity attribute because previously i was facing one issue when i clicked on edittext keyboard covers the field. So after removing the gravity attribute it is working fine.But now i am facing this issue.

```
 <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_267"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_25">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@null"                                          android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789  ^*_,.-"
                            android:ellipsize="start"
                            android:hint="Name"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:maxLength="50"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                            android:singleLine="true"                                android:textColor="@color/login_screen_default_color"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/Grey"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you cannot do anything unless put some whitespace and add cursor after that. so best way is using gravity. what was the issue with gravity? lets solve that

Comment: No you cannot, unless you add some whitespaces in the beginning

Comment: Actually the layout consist of SlidingUpPanel initially it is attach to bottom and it covers the edit text when clicked on it so to solve this i removed the gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Set the gravity to centre and add the following inside onCreate():

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

If the only problem is that your EditText is getting hidden on clicking on it, then the line above will move your layout up when the keyboard shows up.

Comment: I do not have access to my work PC today, so I can't help as I haven't worked with the sliding up panel. If you don't get a solution by tomorrow I will ask you to post more details and we will solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try this? Add OnFocusChangeListener to your EditText and inside onFocusChange, if it has focus and then set the gravity to centre, else set gravity to default i.e top, left, start. Also on back press check, if keyboard is visible then set gravity to default again. I haven't tried, just thought of it now. Let me know.

Comment: Ok i will check this one and let you know once i have done  .

Comment: Change this- if (newGroupActivityBinding.etDesc.isFocusable()) {               To this- if (hasFocus) {

Comment: newGroupActivityBinding.etDesc.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() { @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) { if (hasFocus) { newGroupActivityBinding.etDesc.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); } else { newGroupActivityBinding.etDesc.setGravity(Gravity.NO_GRAVITY); } } }); } as soon as it get Gravity field got covered by

Comment: I have changed that too :( same result

Comment: Go through the issues in that. You might find an issue similar to yours.

Comment: for sure i will let you know .

Answer (score 0):

i made one method for set gravity of hint in center and when its focus gravity set to top left

```
   private void setGravity(final EditText editText) {
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                // position the text type in the left top corner
                editText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);

            } else {
                // no text entered. Center the hint text.
                editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

for keyboard issue you can set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in manifest.xml file and put your all field in scrollview.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    add your widgets here .......
</RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but by using adjustResize user by his own need to scroll the page up.I tried this solution before also but QA does'nt agree with that.

Comment: you can give android:imeOptions="actionNext"

Comment: It is there in a above editText field requirement is like page need to be scrolled up once second editText comes in focus.For that i used adjustPan

Comment: yes you can achieve that by apply each edittext android:imeOptions="actionNext"  and in last edittext apply android:imeOptions="actionDone"